# Angular 2+ select box value is not updating issue

Tags: angular

after loaded all(3 list) select box list it updated ui but on each select box value is not updated why?
[image]

```html
 <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="cat_mid" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Top cat</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select (change)="onChangeTop_()" [(ngModel)]="top_select_val" class="form-control" name="t1">
                                        <option *ngFor="let c22 of topcat_select" [ngValue]="c22"  [attr.value]="c22">{{c22 }}</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="cat_mid" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mid cat</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select (change)="onChangeMid_()" [(ngModel)]="mid_select_val" class="form-control" name="m1">
                                        <option *ngFor="let c21 of midcat_select" [ngValue]="c21" [attr.value]="c21">{{c21 }}</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="cat_mid" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Leaf cat</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select [(ngModel)]="leaf_select_val" class="form-control" name="l1">
                                    <option    *ngFor="let cm3 of leafcat_select" [ngValue]="cm3" [attr.value]="cm3"  >{{cm3}}</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

When i trying check value in mid_select_val it is empty or undefined . 
How to get value now?

if user change any value then it is updating
When we update list it is not calling this function (change)="onChangeMid_()" that is the issue ,How to solve this?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

> Remove `[ngValue]="c21" [attr.value]="c21">` in your select box

or try

> `[ngValue]="top_select_val = c21" [attr.value]=" top_select_val =c21">`

Comment: Now what you are getting?

Comment: when i am trying it is updated in ui bot not passed to ts varable bez it is only call when a change occure

Comment: if user change any value then it is updating

Comment: but when we set top cat programily then mid and leaf select box ui will updated but not getting any value

Comment: in  mid_select_val